# How can I add additional elements to my array?

Tags: javascript

I was trying to get the country name and put it in the *temparray*, so that I can use the *temparray* to check the country (line 14). The problem is *temparray* can only contain one value and upon increasing the array length size by using temparray.length = 4, the heat map won't show up in the page.

The code below is to check duplicate name entry from within the array. If the country name is repeated, it will add the past value and its current value and add it into the data table again as the old row.

```
      var i;
      var suq = 0;
      var temparray = [""];
      var rowcount= 0;

     //set the value
     for (i = 0; i<count; i++){

        var countryname = countryarray[i];
        var hostcount = hosthitcount[i];
        //document.write("hello");
            for (rowcount=0;rowcount<temparray.length;rowcount++){
               //check for any repeated country name
             if (temparray[rowcount] != countryname){

                 data.setValue(suq, 0, countryname);
                 data.setValue(suq, 1, hostcount);
                 temparray[rowcount] = countryname;

               //document.write("win");document.write("<br/>");
                 suq++;

        }else{
                  //get the hits                //rowindex
                  var pastvalue = data.getValue(rowcount,1);

                  //add the previous value with current value
                  var value = parseInt(hostcount)+parseInt(pastvalue);
                  value+= "";
                  //document.write(value);
                  //put it in the table
                 data.setValue(rowcount,1,value);
                 // document.write("lose");document.write("<br/>");
        }
     }

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you are trying to do with `temparray`. It can surely contain more than one element with a `temparray.push(countryname)`. Maybe [this JavaScript array reference](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays) will help you?

Comment: thz. i created the temparray as a count to make the for loop works,so that it can check repeated name in my country array. in the end, i change the temp array into a number like this.

Comment: `               for (rowcount=0;rowcount<number;rowcount++){
                   //check for any repeated country name

                 if (data.getValue(rowcount,0) == countryname ){

                               //get the hits                //rowindex
                      var pastvalue = data.getValue(rowcount,1);

                      //add the previous value with current value
                      var value = parseInt(hostcount)+parseInt(pastvalue);
                      value+= "";
                      data.setValue(rowcount,1,value);    
                 }`

Comment: but still, change of the temparray into var number order check the 1 name in the array as number equal to 1. when i put number++, my code will show no value at my web page

Comment: Oh, I see whats going on. In "temparray[rowcount] = countryname;" you are only ever setting the first index of temparray. Try "temparray.push(countryname)" instead.